# Deezer app on Ubuntu?

Tags: music, music-player

Do you know any solutions that can run Deezer? There is no native app, so it would be wonderful to find some working alternatives

Answer (score 2):

This is browser-like player, but works fine:

```
flatpak remote-add --if-not-exists flathub https://dl.flathub.org/repo/flathub.flatpakrepo
flatpak remote-add --if-not-exists nuvola https://dl.tiliado.eu/flatpak/nuvola.flatpakrepo
flatpak update
flatpak install nuvola eu.tiliado.NuvolaAppDeezer
flatpak run eu.tiliado.NuvolaAppDeezer
```